# Suppress messages in make clean (Makefile silent remove)

Tags: makefile

I'm wondering how I can avoid some echo in a Makefile :

```
clean:
    rm -fr *.o
```

this rule will print:

```
$>make clean   
rm -fr *.o

$>
```

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In fact I was looking for something else, adding this line to the Makefile :

```
.SILENT:clean
```

while execute every step of the "clean" target silently.

Until someone point some drawback to this, I use this as my favourite solution!

Comment: the drawback is that you never get any feedback from your make, and there is no command-line opposite of "silent" to turn it off.  It's like using a sledgehammer to open a jar.

Comment: doesnt work on mac

Answer (score 88):

To start with: the actual command must be on the next line (or at least that is the case with GNU Make, it might be different with other Make's - I'm not sure of that)

```
clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

(note, you need a <kbd>TAB</kbd> before `rm -rf *.o` as in every rule)

Making it silent can be done by prefixing a `@`:

so your makefile becomes

```
clean:
    @rm -rf *.o
```

If there are no `*.o` files to delete, you might still end up with an error message. To suppress these, add the following

```
clean:
    -@rm -rf *.o 2>/dev/null || true
```

- `2>/dev/null` pipes any error message to /dev/null - so you won't see any errors
- the `-` in front of the command makes sure that `make` ignores a non-zero return code

Comment: That is the classic way of dealing it wish bash, but I was looking for the GNU Make way of solving this problem.
And of course I had the command on the next line, just wrote the question in a hurry.
BTW, what do you think of the .SILENT answer (which a friend of mine found) ?

Comment: I haven't really used .silent, the GNU Make manual states that it is only supported for historical reasons, but I do like it. It's less verbose than many `@` in your commands.

Comment: Come to think of it, the `-` and the `|| true` together are too much - either one of them should suffice. You need one of them to prevent Gnu Make from quitting if there is nothing to delete. Better would have been to use `rm -f *.o`, since that doesn't return an error if there is nothing to delete.

Answer (score 32):

I'm responding to this ancient topic because it comes up high in search and the answers are confusing. To do just what the user wants,all that is needed is:

```
clean:
    @rm -f *.o
```

The @ means that make will not echo that command.
The `-f` argument to `rm` tells `rm` to ignore any errors, like there being no `*.o` files, and to return success always.

I removed the -r from the OPs example, because it means recursive and here we are just `rm`ing `.o` files, nothing to recurse.

There's no need for the `2>&1 >/dev/null` because with the `-f` there will be no errors printed.

```
.SILENT: clean
```

works in place of the `@`, but it isn't at the same place in the Makefile as the command that it affects, so someone maintaining the project later might be confused. That's why @ is preferred. It is better locality of reference.

Comment: Just to emphasise my upvote - this really ought to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you put an @ in front of the command, it doesn't echo onto the shell. Try changing rm to @rm. (**[Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html#Echoing)**)

Answer (score 4):

From the manual: [`.SILENT` is essentially obsolete since `@` is more flexible.](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html)

Much worse is that *make* prints far too much information. Warning/error/private messages are buried in the output. On the other hand `-s` (`.SILENT`) suppresses just anything. Especially the "nothing to be done" and "up to date" messages can be a pain. There is no option to suppress them.  You have to filter them out actively or use something like [colormake](https://github.com/pagekite/Colormake). Here is a solution for *grep*:

```
make | egrep -hiv 'nothing to be done|up to date'
```

But the output will have line numbers. The Perl solution is therefore better, because it suppresses line numbers and flushes stdout immediately:

```
make | perl -ne '$|=1; print unless /nothing to be done|up to date/i'
```

Make's a flawed tool. ["What’s Wrong With GNU make?"](http://www.conifersystems.com/whitepapers/gnu-make/) explains this better than I can.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [great article on using `.SILENT`](https://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/) that explains how to conditionally activate it.

I have used that information to put this in my Makefile:

```
# Use `make V=1` to print commands.
$(V).SILENT:

# Example rule, only the @echo needs to be added to existing rules
*.o: %.c
    @echo " [CC]  $<"
    gcc ...
```

What this does is if you run `make` normally, normal output is silenced and instead the `echo` commands work:

```
$ make
 [CC]  test.c
 [CC]  test2.c
```

But it allows you to debug problems by passing the `V=1` parameter, which still shows the `[CC]` messages as it helps break up the output, but the traditional Makefile output is also visible:

```
$ make V=1
 [CC]  test.c
gcc ...
 [CC]  test2.c
gcc ...
```

Comment: Why does this not have more upvotes? SO is so weird sometimes. This is EXACTLY what I was looking for!